# Change Default Value of XML sitemap enable/disable flag

Tags: drush, xml-sitemap

Is there a way to change the default value of a node's XML sitemap enable/disable flag for the [XML sitemap module](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap)?

The default is disabled.  I have a large old site that I want to have completely site-mapped by the module. The documentation I can find says I need to edit every node to enable -- there has to be an easier way.

Barring that, is there a Drush command available for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking 2 things.

The default inclusion status for nodes is set on the node type's edit page (**admin/structure/types/manage/MYTYPE**). The XMLSiteMap settings are stored as `xmlsitemap_settings_node_MYTYPE` in   keyed array (`status` key) if you'd rather `drush vset` the setting.

As for bulk inclusion, the `xmlsitemap` table stores all items index for inclusion/exclusion in your site map. A drush sqlq command can bulk update these settings.

```
#Set all XMLSiteMap node entries as included
drush sqlq 'UPDATE xmlsitemap SET `status` = 1 WHERE `type` = "node"'
drush xmlsitemap-rebuild
```